# Magento - send forgot password email in the customer's language

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a Magento website with 2 languages, when I send a new password to  customer from backend, he received an email in the wrong language, but when he request for a new password from the frontend, he received an email in the correct language.

How can I send the "forgot password email" in the appropriate language (in which the client is created) from the backend ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Is there any known solution to this problem ? I'm searching for hours ! :(

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400660/magento-forgot-password-email-sent-in-wrong-language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step by Step

1. System -> Transactional Emails
2. Click "Add New Template", fill necessary infos
3. Choose the template "New Password" from drop-down list
4. Choose your "locale" or "language settings" from drop-down list
5. Click load template, change what you want ( for instance logo )
6. System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration
7. Click "Password Options" then assing your new email template for "forgot password"

Almost the forgot, you should select store ( I mean related store which is language based ) from "current configuration scope" from upper left corner in configuration section when you set "customer configuration"

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to send Forgot Password Email from localhost.

Only thing you need to do is follow the steps listed below and your done.

1. Modify this page `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`

Comment the existing functionality and add the below code

```
    public function getMail()
    {
     if (is_null($this->_mail)) {
        /* changes begin */
       $my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
       $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port');
       $config = array(
                'port' => $my_smtp_port,
                'auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'your username',
                'password' => 'your password'
            );
        $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host, $config);
        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
        /* Changes End */
        $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
    }
    return $this->_mail;
}
```

2. Login to admin `System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending settings` and set the following things.

   Disable Email Communications = No

   Host = smtp.mandrillapp.com

   Port (25) = 587

   Set Return-Path = No

[image]

3. Login to admin `System -> Transactional Emails -> Add New Template` follow these steps

   - In Load default template - select the required template like `'Forgot Password'` and click on the `Load Template` a default template will be be populated in the template content
   - In Template Information - Provide any template name like `Forgot Password` and click on save template.
4. Login to admin `System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options`

   - In `Forgot Email Template` select 'Forgot Password' (which was created in
     Transactional Emails tab) from the drop down.
   - Select `Remind Email Template` to 'Forgot Password'
   - Select `Forgot and Remind Email Sender` to any drop down value for ex -
     customer support.

[image]

Note - Make Sure the customer support is set to some valid email address. In order modify the customer support email - Login to admin `System -> Configuration -> General -> Store email Address -> Customer support` add the valid email address.

That's all your done. Please feel free to post your queries.
For more info refer this http://pravams.com/2011/07/30/magento-send-email-using-smtp/