# which event is trigger,when a mail is sent by magento store?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to store all emails information,which is sent by magento store.For this i want to trigger a event,after a email is sent by magento store.there are lot of such action is there like when a email is send to user like forget password,registration,newsletter subscribe,wishlist share etc.
There is one idea in my mind that if there is such event is exist in magento like email_send_after,i can add my custum coding in observer file and get that event is trigger or not.but i don't know is there any event or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be interested in [this](http://www.emaildirect.com/magento) but you can always configure the store email section as described [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-general-store-email-addresses) Also check out this [blog post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/last-things-first/) - v helpful

Comment: This is good but my need is advance.I need to store all the information related to email.Just like when a user request for forget password, login information will send to that user.i want to track this.

Comment: check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655332/magento-send-forgot-password-email-in-the-customer-email

Comment: Thanks Rachel,I found a way for this.I have send a custom event in email model,whenever it loads fire custom event and i get this event in observer file.