# Magento "Forgot Password" email sent in wrong language

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.7, multilingual, forgot-password

I have a Magento site with multiple languages. I have setup the language packs and everything seems to translate properly on the website. Also the transactional e-mails are sent in the correct language *EXCEPT for the "**Forgot Password**"* e-mail which is always sent in German. Here's what I did:

- Installed language packs and made sure all templates and folder structures are correct. Example: *`/app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/`*
- Under **System » Transactional Emails**: I applied the template, chose the locale and saved.
- Then I went to **System » Configuration » Sales Emails**, I switched to each language from the "*Current Configuration Scope*" dropdown, and I chose the templates I created in Transactional Emails for each language (each store view).

After looking around online for a solution, it seems others had this problem too and someone mentioned that Magento is picking the "Forgot Password" template from the first locale folder found in */app/locale/*. In my case I had: `de_DE`, `en_US`, `fr_FR`, `nl_NL`. So It picks the template from the German `de_DE` pack.

**NOTE**: Also, in the backend under "Configuration" there's a tab on the left called "LOCALE PACKS" which only has "Locale de_DE" under it, even though I have other language packs which don't show up here. Not sure if this is relevant.

Site: http://site1.cp1.glimworm.com/magento/

Magento Community version: 1.7.0.2

Locale packs:

- Mage_Locale_en_US
- Locale_Mage_community_de_DE
- Locale_Mage_community_fr_FR
- Mage_Locale_nl_NL

**Any idea how I can get the correct email template from the corresponding language to be sent as opposed to always German?** Any help will be greatly appreciated! I can provide more info as well.

Comment: No one has a solution? :(

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem in magento v1.5. After a long research i found this solution and its working for me.

```
Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

in this file i have make some changes as following.
find this line of code
if (!$storeId) 
{
    $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
}

and replace with

$storeId = ($storeId == '0')?$this->getSendemailStoreId():$storeId;
if ($this->getWebsiteId() != '0' && $storeId == '0') 
{
    $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getWebsiteId())->getStoreIds();
    reset($storeIds);
    $storeId = current($storeIds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Although it did not work for me. Just tried it now but the same thing happens: all "Forgot Password" mails sent in German :(
But I am also using v1.7 so maybe there's a difference?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and it looks like user2282917's solution works with a little modify:

You should edit the **sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail** function in the *Customer.php* not the sendNewAccountEmail. Try to replace the code there, and it will working.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the forgotPasswordPostAction controller on the AccountController.php.
You need to set the correct store id so that the locale will be used.

```
/**
 * Forgot customer password action
 */
public function forgotPasswordPostAction()
{
    $email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
    if ($email) {
        if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
            $this->_getSession()->setForgottenEmail($email);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Invalid email address.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
            return;
        }

        /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = $this->_getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
            ->loadByEmail($email);

        if ($customer->getId()) {
            try {
                $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  $this->_getHelper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
                $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);

                // Add store ID so that correct locale will be set
                $customer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

                $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($exception->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_getSession()
            ->addSuccess( $this->_getHelper('customer')
            ->__('If there is an account associated with %s you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.',
                $this->_getHelper('customer')->escapeHtml($email)));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please enter your email.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below file
Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

In sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail function() change the

$storeId = $this->getStoreId();

to

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In our case... We found that when a Customer Account was created by Admin the "email send from" option was not saved and only used for the first account creation email. Any subsequent email sent are sent from the default store view of the website the customer was allocated.

The real problem is how, when the customer store id is identified when none is set.

The method **sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail** (Magento 1.9.1) when the store id is 0 (admin or not set), defaults to *_getWebsiteStoreId* which will return the first store id associated to that website.

The problem is that Magento assumes the first store id associated with the website id is the default store... We found this is not the case when a Sort Order is set against the store record.

Simply put make sure your default store assocaited with a web site is also specified with a sort order of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this link](http://haijerome.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/magento-email-templates/) will be usefull to you

In link they have used New Password but Instead of New Password Use Forgot Password template In step 4

Thanks..

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did try this and I actually already had the same template they use in the example. But then I actually tried to use another template all together but it made no difference. I get the same German template in the mail.

Answer (score 0):

The password reset email is send in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::_sendEmailTemplate()`. Here the emailtemplate is loaded. If it was loaded in admin in "Systemn > Transactional Emails" and configured to be used, your template will be used.

Else the default template is loaded from file in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional`. This is done using `$this->loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);` The template ist loaded using

```
$templateText = Mage::app()->getTranslator()->getTemplateFile(
            $data['file'], 'email', $locale
        );
```

Here locale folders are checked in following order:

1. Specified locale
2. Locale of default store
3. en_US locale

The first matched locale is chosen. As `Mage::app()` doesn't know about the store which was passed with the emailtemplate, the default defaultstore is loaded, which is german in your case. It has nothing to do with the order of the locale folders.

So in your case I suggest to check if your emailtemplate is selected in admin configuration in "System > Config > Customerconfiguration > Password Options" or use `Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::XML_PATH_REMIND_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId)` if it is set for your store.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for why you are receiving the email templates in another language than the one expected is dependent of the language in which you first created your account. Try to check this to be in your own language when you first created the account.

Check this under Customers> Account Information to see how your account was created.

/Kalif