# Magento Transactionnal email cannot choose a new template

Tags: php, magento

When I try to create a new email Template for my transactionnals emails, I get this error :

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Diagnosis_Helper_Data' not found in /home/clients/d23d8bc8181f942eaa5f5f372d7f3ae0/dev/france/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

I cannot find any information about the Mage_Diagnosis_Helper_Data Class...

Comment: Please provide your custom code...

Comment: I don't have a lot of custom code, some modules, but I try do desactivate all of them and nothing change...

Comment: Try doing a search in your project for `Mage::helper('diagnosis')`

Comment: show your config xml file of diagnosis module

Comment: Thanks ! I've found and desactivate the custom module for diagnosis !
And then I use this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17406262/1723027 and now it works !!!